# c++ std::tuple of a variadic type list prefix

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I'm attempting to extract a prefix of types from some variadic type list. Here is my attempt:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Ts>
struct pack{};

template <size_t n, typename... Args>
struct prefix_tuple;

template <size_t n, typename... TPrefix, typename Tnext, typename... Ts>
struct prefix_tuple<n, pack<TPrefix...>, Tnext, Ts...>{
    using type = typename 
        prefix_tuple<n-1, pack<TPrefix..., Tnext>, Ts...>::type;
};

template <typename... TPrefix, typename... Ts>
struct prefix_tuple<0, pack<TPrefix...>, Ts...>{
    using type = std::tuple<TPrefix...>;
};

template <size_t n, typename... Args>
using prefix_tuple_t = typename 
    prefix_tuple<n, pack<>, Args...>::type;

bool f(){
    return std::is_same_v<prefix_tuple_t<2, int, char, double>,
                          std::tuple<int, char> >;
}
```

This fails on gcc 8.2 with:

> error: ambiguous template instantiation for 'struct prefix_tuple<0, pack< int, char>, double>'

The second specialization appears to be more specific than the first, so I don't see why there's ambiguity here.
What am I doing wrong?

P.S. This also fails on clang 7.0 with a similar error, but appears to work on icc 19.0.1 and msvc 19.16.

Comment: The gcc/clang versions work if I add the specialization:
template <typename... TPrefix, typename Tnext, typename... Ts>
struct prefix_tuple<0, pack<TPrefix...>, Tnext, Ts...>{...};
However, with this addition icc fails to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research, here are my findings:

These are the [Partial Ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) rules:

> 1) If only one specialization matches the template arguments, that
>   specialization is used.
>   2) If more than one specialization matches, partial order rules are used to determine which specialization is more specialized. **The most specialized specialization is used, if it is unique (if it is not unique, the program cannot be compiled)**.
>   3) If no specializations match, the primary template is used

And:

> Informally "*A* is more specialized than *B*" means "*A* accepts a subset of the types that *B* accepts".

Let *A* and *B* be the first and second specializations in my code, respectively.
*A* accepts structs with numbers `n` grater than 0 (which *B* does not). On the other hand, *B* accepts structs with 0 types following the prefix pack (which *A* does not). Therefore neither *A* nor *B* is "most specialized", and the program should not compile.
That is, icc and msvc are wrong.

---

### Possible solution:

Suppose I add the following third specialization (call it *C*) mentioned in my comment:

```
template <typename... TPrefix, typename Tnext, typename... Ts>
struct prefix_tuple<0, pack<TPrefix...>, Tnext, Ts...>{
    using type = std::tuple<TPrefix...>;
};
```

*C* does not accept either numbers `n` grater than 0, or structs with 0 types follwing the prefix pack. It is therefore the most specialized. Furthermore, if `n==0` and *C* can't be used, neither can *A*, so this resolves the ambiguity between *A* and *B*.

With this addition, the code works with gcc, clang and msvc, but icc rejects it with the following error:

> error: more than one partial specialization matches the template argument
>   list of class "prefix_tuple<0UL, pack < int, char >,
>   double>":
>   "prefix_tuple<0UL, pack < TPrefix... >, Tnext, Ts...>"
>   "prefix_tuple<0UL, pack < TPrefix... >, Ts...>"

As I mentioned earlier, the first of these (*C*) is more specialized than the second (*B*), so I must deduce that icc is wrong again.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, you might use `std::index_sequence`:

```
template <typename Seq, typename Tuple> struct prefix_tuple_impl;

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename Tuple>
struct prefix_tuple_impl<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple>
{
    using type = std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>...>;
};

template <std::size_t N, typename ... Ts>
using prefix_tuple_t = typename prefix_tuple_impl<std::make_index_sequence<N>,
                                                  std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2db1a9290083bc44)